# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'female'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

When I run the following code, it does not perform one-hot encoding

```
tf1 = ColumnTransformer([
    ('impute1',SimpleImputer(strategy="mean"),[2]),
    ('impute2',SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"),[6]),
],remainder='passthrough')

tf2 = ColumnTransformer([
    ("encoder1",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore'),[1]),
    ("encoder2",OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore'),[6])
],remainder='passthrough')

tf3 = ColumnTransformer([
    ('scaler',StandardScaler(),[5])
],remainder='passthrough')

model = RandomForestClassifier()

pipe = make_pipeline(tf1,tf2,tf3,model)
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

and I get the following error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'female'
```

But when I run only `tf2` (encoder column transformer) it encodes the column as expected

```
tf2.fit_transform(X_train)[0]
>>array([  1.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,   0.    ,
         1.    ,  58.    ,   0.    ,   0.    , 146.5208])
```

Answer (score 0):

Stacking `ColumnTransformers` in a pipeline and passing numeric column indices is error-prone.

Steps like `OneHotEncoder` change the order of features. So in the current image of the pipeline, imputing on `[1]` and `[6]` in the second step may not be the columns you're expecting. Here's what the current pipeline looks like:

[image: An image of a scikit-learn pipeline with three column transformers being fed into each other, before being passed into a random forest classifier.]

Instead, handle your numeric and categorical features with individual pipelines, and combine the two with a column transformer:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline, Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

titanic, target = fetch_openml(data_id=40945, parser="auto", return_X_y=True)
titanic = titanic[["pclass", "sex", "age", "sibsp", "parch", "fare", "embarked"]]

cat_columns = ["sex", "pclass", "embarked"]
numeric_features = ["age", "fare"]

numeric_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("impute_mean", SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")),
        ("scaler", StandardScaler())])
categorical_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("impute_frequent", SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")),
        ("ohe", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"))])

pipe = make_pipeline(
    ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("categorical", categorical_pipeline, cat_columns),
            ("numeric", numeric_pipeline, numeric_features),
        ],
        remainder="passthrough",
    ),
    RandomForestClassifier(),
)
```

[image: Simplified pipeline with numeric features and categorical variables handled separately.]